# CentOS 6.4 rpm requires el5 but available is only el6

Tags: centos, rpm

I want to install `lipXp-devel-1.0.0-8.1.el5.i386.rpm` and get the error message:

> Package: lipXp-devel-1.0.0-8.1.el5.i386
>   Requires: libXp = 1.0.0-8.1.el5
>   Installed: libXp-1.0.0-15.1.el6.i686

How can I install the the rpm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you are misjudging it. Your rpm file version is older and you have installed CentOS6.4 requires el6 package, which is NOT compatible to your system.

You need to install `lipXp-devel` package compatible to your installed `libXp-1.0.0-15.1.el6.i686` package. This package is available on rpm.pbone.net
Try installing [this package](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=26&dist=79&size=17156&name=libXp-devel-1.0.0-15.1.el6.i686.rpm).

Comment: @nguvi: If you find my answer helpful and resolved your issue, Please mark the answer accepted. So that, it will come at top of other answers and will helpful to others who refer this question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for the quick answer! I had to experiment a little but you explanation put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the el6 version of libXp-devel to avoid a lot of dependency issues. If you have the el6 repository configured you should be able to search for the correct version using `yum search libXp-devel` and to install the package (including dependencies) using `yum install libXp-devel`

To configure the el6 repo you can use:

```
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

See http://repoforge.org/use/ for details.

You can also use the 'community approved repository':

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-6-6.el6.elrepo.noarch.rpm 
yum install yum-plugin-fastestmirror
```

See https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories and http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php for details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! i configured the repositories!